# How to translate QNetworkReply errors?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, translation, qnetworkreply

I am working with QNetworkReply::NetworkError and I can get the string error with it name by using

```
reply->errorString()
```

Is there some possibilities in Qt to translate that string without any hard-code-dictionary for example to Spanish?

Comment: Hmm in pure Qt probably not. Better question is why you want to do that?

Comment: Some strings of QNetworkReply implementation is in qtbase_xx.ts. You can try to use ready qtbase_xx.qm or translate it by yourself.

Comment: Qt does not come with a built in automatic translator. Your best bet could be to use the QTranslator class and provide the translations yourself, but then it's the same as hard coding.